# Handling on Jersey (JAX-RS) on XMLHttpRequest abort

Tags: java, jersey, xmlhttprequest, jax-rs, abort

I'm using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) for the application's REST API, consider the function below

```
@POST
public String writeSomething() {
    someVeryIntensiveTaskWhichTaking("5 seconds");
    Log.info("get request fulfilled") // don't want the logging to happen if user cancelled on UI
    return "ok";
}
```

Assume this POST request is doing some intensive task and might takes up to 5 seconds. Then on the UI, the user decided to cancel the POST request via [XMLHttpRequest.abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) at 2 second,

is there any way to track this abortion and prevent some action being done? something like checking `IsClientConnected`?

#### Update #1

Thanks to peeskillet's tips, but i still unable to get the callback being triggered upon the XHR's abortion. The below is my code

```
@POST
public String writeSomething(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    asyncResponse.register(new ConnectionCallback() {
        public void onDisconnect(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
            System.out.println("This is canceled, do whatever you want"); // this is not triggered after XHR aborted
        }
    });
    someVeryIntensiveAsynTaskWhichTaking("5 seconds", asyncResponse); // this asyn function will trigger asyncResponse.resume() upon completion
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately. I think this method only affects the browser. The server won't be aware that the client closed the connection.

Comment: If you're using Jersey 2, take a look at [asynchronous processing](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10317) and the `ConnectionCallback`